# Issue with logging exceptions

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j, log4j2

After porting big project to log4j2, i noticed that logging of exceptions doesn't work. Such code

```
logger.error("Error occurred", e);
```

doesn't log exception call stack. The log for the above line contains only:

```
21/07/2013 15:51:34 ERROR [MyTask-1] [MyManager] Error occurred
```

Please help to configure the logger.

Updated:
My log4j2.xml generally looks like this (i removed rest of the appenders and loggers):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration name="server" monitorInterval="30">
<appenders>
    <!-- ################# All Appender ############################### -->
    <RollingFile name="AllAppender" fileName="${sys:workspace}/logs/all.log" filePattern="${sys:workspace}/archive/logs/all_%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH}.log">
        <PatternLayout>
            <pattern>%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss} %-5p [%t] [%c{1}] %m%n</pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy />
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB"/>
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="50"/>
    </RollingFile>

</appenders>

<loggers>
    <!-- #################################################################################################### -->
    <!-- ################################### Loggers definitions ############################################ -->
    <!-- #################################################################################################### -->

    <logger name="com" level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="AllAppender" />
    </logger>

    <root level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="AllAppender"/>
    </root>

</loggers>
```

**By the way, monitorInterval doesn't work for me. I have to restart tomcat in order to update logger configuration.**

Comment: What does your current configuration look like? The [log4j Manual](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html) explains the various ways to configure it

Comment: It's a big project so, my config file is very long. What part of the config is relevant? I've red the manual and configured everything. This is the only issue for now.

Comment: What is the pattern you are using to configure the format that log events are written to the file?

Comment: Added pattern to post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What version of log4j2 are you using? I remember this being an issue in older betas but it was fixed around beta5 or so... If you are using a recent beta, could you file a bug report?

As a workaround you can replace `%m%n` at the end of your pattern with `%m%ex%n`.

Comment: Thanks! I have beta 2. I will check the w/a ASAP, also i will try upgrade the log4j2 version. Do you know why monitorInterval doesn't work? Is it also known issue of old beta?

Comment: We used jars from nexus central which were not updated. After upgrade to beta 8 from Apache site, both issues were resolved. Thank you for help.